# How to divide a convex Polygon in Minimum rectangle and Triangle?

Tags: polygon

I Have a Convex Polygon that I want to divide into the **Minimum Number of Rectangles and Triangles**.

Is there any algorithm to divide it?

Comment: Start with "Split polygon into minimum amount of rectangles and triangles." [a previous MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28303/split-polygon-into-minimum-amount-of-rectangles-and-triangles).